# Process exiting after opening >2.5k TCP ports and threads

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-c++, tcp

The process (written in C++) is acting as a server, QTcpServer class is used to construct the server. For every new incoming connection, it spawns a new thread and creates a QTcpSocket object with new socket descriptor, which takes care of all reads/writes on that socket. It may sound bad, to spawn a new thread for every connection, but I can't help with that, so please bear with it.
So, the problem is, when number of sockets at server goes beyond 2500, it crashes. I get the below message on console:
QEventDispatcher: Failed to create QEventDispatcherWin32 internal window: 1158
Qt: INTERNALL ERROR: failed to install GetMessage hook

I tried few things, first I checked can we create these many threads or not, as there is dedicated thread for every connection. There is no problem with it, I could create more than 5000 threads. 
Second, I found something at MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx
It also didn't help. Please suggest.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681383(v=vs.85).aspx - 1158 would be ERROR_NO_MORE_USER_HANDLES (which I know nothing about, but maybe that can help you find a solution)

Comment: Yes, I also looked that, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Possibly of interest here:  http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx

Comment: I monitored handles count, it's not crossing the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Each thread has a default allocation of 1 MB to its stack, so with 2500 threads your thread stacks have exceeded the 2 GB of memory available to a process. The one-thread-per-socket design is untenable for so many sockets.

Comment: that is not a problem, as I have mentioned in my question, I could create more than 5000 threads, if it was a problem, then it could not have created these many threads. Moreover I monitored Memory(Private working set) of the process, it was ~400MB.

Answer (score 0):

There were few things, at first compiled the executable for 64bit platform. It helped to create large number of threads. Secondly, dropped using QTcpSocket, and wrote all functions from scratch. The difference which I seek from QTcpSocket, is the way "Winsock2.h" is included. Before including the header file defined the below macro.
    #define FD_SETSIZE 5000

With these changes, server could handle >5K requests simultaneously, and CPU usage was not much too.